# Which Japanese Particle should go here, (ni) or (wa)?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-は

わたしの　いえ＿　へやが　みっつ　あります。

Essentially what I'm trying to say here is, "There are three rooms in my house"...
What should go after ie (house)?

Comment: に, は, or には all eligible depending your context...

Answer (score 5):

It would be best to denote the house as both the location (of the rooms) and the topic of the sentence by using both.

「私{わたし}の家{いえ}には部屋{へや}が三{みっ}つあります。」
In my house [←topic], there are three rooms.'
Colloquially: 'There are three rooms in my house.'